# $ (M, \mathcal{M}_C, \mu_{1/2} $ is a measure space wher $C$ is the cantor set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to show $ (M, \mathcal{M}_C, \mu_{1/2} $) is a measure space where $\mu_{1/2}$ is defined as:

$$\mu_{1/2}(I_{\underline{\omega}}) = \frac{1}{2^n}   $$

given $I_{\underline{\omega}} = I_{\omega_0 \omega_1 \omega_2 ..... \omega_n} $ is an interval in the cantor set $C$ and the $\omega_i =$ $0$ or $1$. And

$$\mathcal{M}_C = \{ E \cap C : E \in \mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{R}} \} $$ and $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\sigma - algebra$ over the real with standard lebesgue measure. I know to show that the triple above is a measure we can use the fact that we already have $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is a sigma algebra. But, how can we prove this from scratch? Do I need to show $\mu_{1/2}$ is a measure, or can we assume? Can someone help me solve this problem? thanks

Comment: This is not a measure space, because $\mu_{1/2}$ is not a measure. A measure must be defined on all of $\mathcal{M}_C$, but  $\mu_{1/2}$ is only defined on the intervals. What is true, is that it can be extended to a unique measure on $\mathcal{M}_C$.

Comment: How can we do this? Can you explain? thanks

Comment: Use the [Carathéodory extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_extension_theorem).